# how to add json through mapping material-ui grid component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image]

I want to add json data to 4`ColorCards` like the pic,but ``` title``color``rating ``` fail the render,please see the code below:

```
import ColorCard from "./ColorCard"
import React from "react"
import data from "./initialState.json"

export default function ColorCards(){
const dataColors=data.colors
  return(
    dataColors.map(
      (n,color)=>(
        <ColorCard 
        key={color.id}
        title={color.title}
        color={color.color}
        rating={color.rating}
      

        />
      )
    )

  )
}
```

The full project link:https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-62eh0?file=/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-pnnz1?file=/ColorCards.js) is the working sandbox.

All I do is converting from `(n,color)=>(` to `(color)=>(`

Read more about how `map` works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/vi/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)